# Wordpress customize error messages database

Tags: wordpress

I want to customize the "Error establishing database connection" or other error messages in Wordpress to say something more friendly  like "Database down please visit our alternate site http://static.msdnetworks.com"

I want to avoid hacking the code it seems to be all built in with wp-db.php - so upgrades will not be painful.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own page for this error. Create your custom page, name it `db-error.php`, and upload it to the `wp-content` directory. See for example this [doc](https://digwp.com/2009/11/custom-database-error-page/)